# How to set both Starting_Value and Auto_Increment size for a table in MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to be able to set both the following values for a primary key :-

1. Auto_Increment_size - the difference between 2 auto generated IDs.
2. Starting_Value - the starting value

Example values to be generated with :-

1. starting value = 1, auto_increment_size = 100 : 1, 101, 201, 301, ..
2. starting value = 2, auto_increment_size = 100 : 2, 102, 202, 302, ..

Reason:
Consider 2 way replicated Database - For a table called Users (ID: primary key)
The ID generated in DB1 should never be generated in DB2, else it would result in replication conflict.

In SQL Server, this can be achieved (starting value 2, increment by 100) using :-

CREATE TABLE Persons (
Personid int IDENTITY(2,100) PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int
);

With ORACLE DB it can be done using SEQUENCE

How can i achieve this using MySQL ?

Comment: MySQl doesn't directly support this functionality.  You would need to use a trigger.

Comment: Use regular autoincrement. Calculate needed value in a query based on autoincremented value when needed.

Comment: You may, of course, set `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset`, but they acts on global or session level, not on table level.

Comment: @Akina - can you give more details on your approach using regular auto increment? how would the query look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373582/how-to-auto-increment-by-2-for-a-particular-table-in-mysql

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c7aff9ffd5e71e37ccf3d339c31efdb3 Also test the same using 2 or more connections (fiddle cannot reproduce this).